# Shrinking navigation bar when scrolling down (bootstrap3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to build a navigation-bar effect like it is on http://dootrix.com/ on my page (after scrolling down the bar getting smaller and the logo changes). Im using bootstrap 3 for my page. Is there an easy way to realize it with bootstrap?

Comment: Attempting for it or trying out something ... Would be a good option!

Comment: There is a really great article below ...

Comment: this is old question but this tutorial is useful for this question (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) and this tutorial (http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_affix.asp)

Comment: The example link is no longer valid.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

### Sticky navbar:

To make a sticky nav you need to add the class **navbar-fixed-top** to your nav

**Official documentation**:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/#placement

**Official example**:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

**A simple example code**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

with related **jsfiddle**:  http://jsfiddle.net/ur7t8/

### Resize the navbar:

If you want  the nav bar to  resize while you scroll the page you can give a look to this example: http://www.bootply.com/109943

***JS***

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});
```

***CSS***

```
nav.navbar.shrink {
  min-height: 35px;
}
```

### Animation:

To add an animation while you scroll, all you need to do is set a transition on the nav

***CSS***

```
nav.navbar{
  background-color:#ccc;
   // Animation
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
   transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
```

---

I made a **jsfiddle** with the full example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/Filo/m7yww8oa/

Comment: This would work, but there is no fancy animation to resize the navbar.

Comment: I updated my answer, now it has resize animation. Please mark as accepted answer if my solution it's what you need.

Comment: Mind you that, in Filo's (correct) answer you need to define an original height in your stylesheet to make the animation work. If the height of your element solely depends on padding for instance, the animation won't work. It literally needs to read e.g. `height: 100px` as the original state before the animation.

Comment: I think you need to use `fixed-top` instead of `navbar-fixed-top` in bootstrap v4.x

Answer (score 14):

toggleClass works too:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    $("nav").toggleClass("shrink", $(this).scrollTop() > 50)
});
```

Answer (score 5):

For those not willing to use *jQuery* here is a Vanilla Javascript way of doing the same using *classList*:

```
function runOnScroll() {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName('nav')  ;
    if(document.body.scrollTop >= 50) {
        element[0].classList.add('shrink')
    } else {
        element[0].classList.remove('shrink')
    }
    console.log(topMenu[0].classList)

};
```

There might be a nicer way of doing it using *toggle*, but the above works fine in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can combine "scroll" and ["scrollstop"](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_scrollstop.asp) events in order to achieve desired result:

```
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
   $('nav').addClass('shrink');
}); 
$(window).on("scrollstop",function(){
   $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AngularJS, and you are using Angular Bootstrap : https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

You can do this so nice like this :

**HTML:**

```
<nav id="header-navbar" class="navbar navbar-default" ng-class="{'navbar-fixed-top':scrollDown}" role="navigation" scroll-nav>
    <div class="container-fluid top-header">
        <!--- Rest of code --->
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:** (*Note* here I use padding as bigger nav to shrink without padding you can modify as you want)

```
nav.navbar {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;

  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
  padding: 0;
}
```

And then add your directive

**Directive**: (*Note* you may need to change `this.pageYOffset >= 50` from 50 to more or less to fulfill your needs)

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('scrollNav', function ($window) {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
    angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
      if (this.pageYOffset >= 50) {
        scope.scrollDown = true;
      } else {
        scope.scrollDown = false;
      }
      scope.$apply();
    });
  };
});
```

This will do the job nicely, animated and cool way.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code for my project

```
$(window).scroll ( function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
        document.getElementById('your-div').style.height = '100px'; //For eg
    } else {
        document.getElementById('your-div').style.height = '150px';
    }    
}
);
```

Probably this will help