# Bootstrap shrinking header on scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have seen this on a variety of websites, and I really liked it. So I looked up how to do it, and I found this page: [Shrinking navigation bar when scrolling down (bootstrap3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765155/shrinking-navigation-bar-when-scrolling-down-bootstrap3)

I copied almost everything (except the animation), and incorporated it into my website. I have no idea why it does not work.

My code is here:
http://www.bootply.com/xeJAvLd2u8

Comment: Im not seeing a <nav> tag in your html anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I forked yours and wrapped your navigation in a

```
<nav>
```

tag, it works now.

http://www.bootply.com/Kh4iGxIopA