# Resizing Header On Scroll Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

My question is about AngularJS, in response to events (scroll) . I need to change the size of the header on scroll down or resize on scroll up. The code in javascript is next, but I need to implement it in AngularJs:

```js
function init() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
        var distanceY = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
            shrinkOn = 300,
            header = document.querySelector("header");
        if (distanceY > shrinkOn) {
            classie.add(header,"smaller");
        } else {
            if (classie.has(header,"smaller")) {
                classie.remove(header,"smaller");
            }
        }
    });
}
window.onload = init();
```

```css
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    background-color: #0683c9;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s;
    transition: height 0.3s;
}
header h1#logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 150px;
    float: left;
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}
header nav a {
    line-height: 150px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #9fdbfc;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
header.smaller {
    height: 75px;
}
header.smaller h1#logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
header.smaller nav a {
    line-height: 75px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 660px) {
    header h1#logo {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 100px;
        line-height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    header nav {
        display: block;
        float: none;
        height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    header nav a {
        line-height: 50px;
        margin: 0 10px;
    }
    header.smaller {
        height: 75px;
    }
    header.smaller h1#logo {
        height: 40px;
        line-height: 40px;
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    header.smaller nav {
        height: 35px;
    }
    header.smaller nav a {
        line-height: 35px;
    }
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1 id="logo">
            LOGO
        </h1>
        <nav>
            <a href="">Lorem</a>
            <a href="">Ipsum</a>
            <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header><!-- /header -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add/remove class 'shrink' based on scroll bottom/top respectively in angular controller.

```
//inside your controller
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
});

//your css
.shrink {
     height: 35px;// set height you which you want while scrolling down
}
```

[Reference stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765155/shrinking-navigation-bar-when-scrolling-down-bootstrap3)