# Switching CSS of navigation bar when scrolling down

Tags: css

I'm trying to make fixed navigation bar with modifying Bootstrap CSS file. If I scroll down, navbar's color should be changed and fixed to the top.

So I've added following JS code by referring to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24765232/9225379) but it doesn't work.

```
let MQL = 992;

if ($(window).width() > MQL) {
  let headerHeight = $("#mainNav").height();

  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
      $("#mainNav").addClass("is-visible");
    } else {
      $("#mainNav").removeClass("is-visible");
    }
  });
}
```

`#mainnav` is CSS for navigation bar, and `is-visible` is CSS animation for displaying navbar. `992` is mininum width for desktop screen.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Luberen/ty15jho7/13/)

How to I solve this?

Comment: Your fiddle does not even have any JS or HTML, so what is wrong?

Comment: @Justinas Because it depends on Bootstrap file so code will be very long, I added JS/HTML code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the working solution here.

```js
    var headerHeight = $(".clearHeader").height();


$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= headerHeight) {
        $(".clearHeader").addClass("is-visible");
    }else{
      $(".clearHeader").removeClass("is-visible");
    }
});
```

```css
    .clearHeader{
height: 200px; 
background-color: rgba(107,107,107,0.66);
position: fixed;
top:200;
width: 100%;

}


.is-visible {height: 100px;background-color:#1e1e1e}


.wrapper {
height:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="clearHeader">
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer has hardcoded values - opposite as OP has in his code. What if my header is dynamic height?

Comment: @NBlizz Is it helped ?

Comment: Mark this as an answer if it is a solution to you.